# How to insert into mutiple tables with Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I am trying to insert into 2 different tables(House and Contact) using a single method.

```
public function store(HouseRequest $request){

    $dataForm = $request->all();

    $house = House::create($dataForm); //Insert into House table
    $contact = $house->contact()->create($dataForm['contact']); //Insert into Contact table


    return back('dashboard/houses')->with('message', 'Success');
}
```

Here is my table Contact:

```
  Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {    
        $table->integer('house_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->char('phone', 11);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('house_id')->references('id')->on('houses')->onDelete('cascade')
  }
```

House Model:

```
public function contact(){
    return $this->hasOne(Contact::class);
}
```

It works fine (inserts into both tables), but after submitting the form, I got this:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `contacts` where `id` = 0 limit 1)

I don't know why it is running the query above. How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to add a column for ids add `$table->increments('id');` in your migration :

```
Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) { 
    $table->increments('id');   
    $table->integer('house_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name', 255);
    $table->char('phone', 11);
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('house_id')->references('id')->on('houses')->onDelete('cascade')
}
```

Comment: It was so simple, I really need to get some sleep;